# Flask: stream file upload without form boundary data to file

Tags: flask, file-upload

I want to upload large files using flask. Rather than try to load the entire file into memory, I've implemented the request.stream.read() method to stream the file to disk in chunks, as per the following code, which is very similar to answers given to many similar questions I have found:

```
@app.route("/uploadData", methods=["POST"])
def uploadData():
filename = uuid.uuid4().hex + '.nc'
filePath = os.path.join("/tmp", filename)

with open(filePath, "wb+") as f:
    chunk_size = 4096
    while True:
        chunk = flask.request.stream.read(chunk_size)
        if len(chunk) == 0:
            break
        f.write(chunk)

return flask.jsonify({'success': True, 'filename': filename})
```

This works well, except that it "wraps" the file in post data, like the following:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryoQ8GPdNkcfUNrKBd
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="inputFile"; filename="some_file_upload.nc"
Content-Type: application/x-netcdf

<Actual File content here>
------WebKitFormBoundaryoQ8GPdNkcfUNrKBd--
```

How can I stream the file to disk without getting the form boundary stuff?

In theory, I could call `flask.request.file` or the like to get the file correctly, but as that loads the entire file into memory (or more likely a temporary file), and is quite slow relative to the stream method, I don't like it as a solution.

If it makes a difference, I'm initiating the file upload using the following javascript:

```
var formData=new FormData($('#fileform')[0])

$.ajax({
    url:'/uploadData',
    data:formData,
    processData:false,
    contentType:false,
    type:'POST'
    })
```

EDIT: I've managed to work around the issue by using readline() rather than read(), discarding the first four lines, and then checking for chunk starting with "---" to discard the last line, which works. However, this feels both kludgy and fragile, so if there is a better solution, I would love to hear it.

Comment: _load the entire file into memory_ are you sure that flask writes entire file into a memory? Because [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/fileuploads/#improving-uploads) and [here](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest._get_file_stream) is stated that if body exceeds a certain threshold (500KB) it would be handled with a temporary file, not RAM.

Comment: Ok, yeah. So that would explain why it is so slow: it reads the file in, writes it to a temporary file, then has to read it again to write it to the permanent file. Regardless however, the fact remains that handling the request WITHOUT using stream.read is SIGNIFICANTLY slower than using string.read, and as such not a good solution.

Comment: Well, if you care that much about performance, I really doubt that any Python implementation of file upload would beat [professionally C-written web-server that is designed to decently serve static files](https://www.nginx.com/). But if you want to do it Python-way without writing your own form parser (which is _hard_), you can send file to a separate endpoint from your form and write fast code to save it or take a look at [how Werkzeug parses files in a form](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/formparser.py#L491) and how you can tune it for your needs.

Comment: @fian I don't think you need to care too much about performance to want to transfer the file in 13 seconds vs. 70 or so. And for what it's worth, I've done this exact thing using the CherryPy framework without issue. I find it surprising that the flask implementation would be broken like this, with no good workaround/fix, but oh well.